# Create API to view logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have used Winston to view logs in console as well as in application.How to create an API to view log files of my NodeJS server in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have the log file created by winston. You can write an API as below:

```
app.get('/logs', function (req, res, next) {

    var filePath = "path to your log file";

    res.sendFile(filePath, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Sent the logs..');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am able to view logs after calling API